# Need to loop a code to grab text from a document and paste it into another document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document that has multiple subject lines - I think someone copied and pasted 100 emails into one Word document. I want to grab all the subject lines and paste them into a new document for further modification.

I've used a mix of code I've found on here to get close. So far I'm able to grab the first iteration of the subject and paste it into the new document, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop it so it keeps running down the document, i.e. to capture the other "99" instances of subjects. This is what I was trying

```
Sub SubjectFind()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSeciton

    For I = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim strTheText As String
    Dim DestFileNum As Long
    Dim sDestFile As String

    sDestFile = “C:\Users\pascualt\Documents\Doc1.txt” ‘Location of External File
    DestFileNum = FreeFile()

    Open sDestFile For Output As DestFileNum ‘This opens new file with name DestFileNum
    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
    If rng1.Fine.Execute(Findtext:=”Subject:”) Then
        Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
        If rng2.Fine.Execute(Findtext:=”Ref:”) Then
            strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range (rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
            Print #DestFileNum, strTheText ‘Print # will write to external file
        End If
    End If
    Application.Browser.Next
        Next I
    Close #DestFileNum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, for example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrOut As String, wdDoc As Document
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Subject:*^13"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    StrOut = StrOut & .Text
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Set wdDoc = Documents.Add
wdDoc.Range.Text = StrOut
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```